# Applying function to dataframe for each group using dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the mean of each group/factor and creating a new column with the group mean for each case, using dplyr piping.

My code is as follows:

```
mtcars = mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl),]

newdf = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(meanweight = mean(wt)) %>% as.data.frame()

newdf

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb meanweight
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    3.21725
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2    3.21725
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2    3.21725
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1    3.21725
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    3.21725
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1    3.21725
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1    3.21725
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1    3.21725
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2    3.21725
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2    3.21725
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2    3.21725
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    3.21725
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    3.21725
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    3.21725
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    3.21725
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4    3.21725
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4    3.21725
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6    3.21725
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    3.21725
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4    3.21725
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3    3.21725
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3    3.21725
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3    3.21725
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4    3.21725
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4    3.21725
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4    3.21725
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2    3.21725
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2    3.21725
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4    3.21725
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2    3.21725
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4    3.21725
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8    3.21725
```

However, the meanweight for all cases are the same. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I just realized that the meanweight is just the mean of the whole data. How do I get the mean of each group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be that there is also `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr` masking the `dplyr` version of `mutate`.  One option is to explicitly specify the `dplyr::mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(meanweight = mean(wt))
```

Comment: Ahh, that solves the issue. It was working for a while, and then did not work all of a sudden. I assumed it happened because I loaded another package along the way that might have masked dplyr. Thank you!

Comment: @TYL  It usually happens when we load of packages.  Sometimes, there will be a message stating these packages got masked...